# How can i pull to refresh webview in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, webview

I want to refresh webview page just when i swipe down the page. I found this code.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:rivlus_webview_app/common_widgets/alert_dialog.dart';

class NewWebView extends StatefulWidget {
const NewWebView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<NewWebView> createState() => _NewWebViewState();
}

class _NewWebViewState extends State<NewWebView> {
WebViewController? _controller;
double progress = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      final result = await const CommonAlertDialog(
        title: 'Çıkış Yap',
        content: 'Uygulamadan çıkış yapmak istediğinize emin misiniz?',
        mainButtonText: 'Evet',
        cancelButtonText: 'Vazgeç',
      ).show(context);
      if (result == true) {
        return exit(0);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    child: WebView(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller = webViewController;
      },
      gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
              ..onDown = (DragDownDetails dragDownDetails) {
                _controller!.getScrollY().then((value) {
                  if (value == 0 &&
                      dragDownDetails.globalPosition.direction < 1) {
                    _controller!.reload();
                  }
                });
              })),

    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

This is work. But when I click on the top of the screen, it refreshes the page. I dont want this. I just want it to refresh the page when I pull the page down. How can I do that. Thanks.

Thanks for everyone. I solved this problem with inappwebview_flutter package.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing this problem a lot while using web view the **pull to refresh** plugin is not working. Then I came across a solution that was very easy to use.

> First declare a late variable of **WebViewController**:

```
late WebViewController webViewController;
```

> Create WebView Widget and on it initialize webviewContoller in **onWebViewCreated** and use **gestureRecognizers** for pull to refresh:

```
             WebView(
                      gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                      initialUrl: 'yourwebsitelink',
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated:
                          (WebViewController webViewController) {
                        this.webViewController = webViewController;
                      },
                      zoomEnabled: false,
                      gestureRecognizers: Set()
                        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onDown = (DragDownDetails dragDownDetails) {
                                webViewController
                                    .getScrollY()
                                    .then((value) {
                                  if (value == 0 &&
                                      dragDownDetails
                                              .globalPosition.direction <
                                          1) {
                                    webViewController.reload();
                                  }
                                });
                              }
                          ),
                       ),
                     
                    )
```

Hope this will solve your issue. Don't forget to give thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) for swipe refresh.

onRefresh method of SmartRefresher